# Is it possible to integrate Mercurial commits with JIRA or FishEye (via TortoiseHg or hg)?

Tags: mercurial, jira, tortoisehg, atlassian-fisheye

Is there a way to link every HG commit to a specific bug tracking issue?

For example, show a drop down when committing from TortoiseHg with all active JIRA issues assigned to the current user (similar to the [TortoiseSVN Plugin for JIRA](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/10017)). Maybe a drop down is too fancy, but is there something similar to the [TortoiseSVN Integration with Bug Tracking Systems / Issue Trackers](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) available at least, i.e. a text box in the top right of the commit window where you can enter the issue number? Can't seem to find anything similar in THG.

I found some promising configurations in the [TortoiseHg manual](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.0/changelog.html#message-parsing) but find them very primitive... Ideas/thoughts/workarounds?

Comment: Ok, so in the repo .hg\hgrc file I was able to get a link to show up..by adding:

[tortoisehg]
issue.regex = #(\d+)\b
issue.link = http://JIRA_SERVER/browse/PROJECT_NAME-{1}


Would be nice if I can get that to FishEye..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no -- TortoiseHg does not support the features you ask for. The feature has already been [entered into TortoiseHg's bug tracker](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/issue/369/allow-external-bug-traq-extensions), so I suggest you sign up at Bitbucket and "follow" the issue there.

Answer (score 6):

It's there now.

Go to `File/Settings/`, then choose either the `global settings` tab or the repository's one.

Under `Issue Tracking` add the appropriate regex and link. For example `\b\w{3,7}-\d+\b` and `http://your.jira.server.com:8080/browse/{0}`.

See http://caraulean.com/blog/2011/09/09/tortoisehg-and-jira-integrationthe-lightweight-option/

Answer (score 3):

fyi, this was addressed by the TortoiseHg team about two weeks ago.  it is currently in nightly builds, but will likely make it into the next real release.